# Haskell newbie on types

Tags: haskell

I'm completely new to Haskell (and more generally to functional programming), so forgive me if this is really basic stuff. To get more than a taste, I try to implement in Haskell some algorithmic stuff I'm working on. I have a simple module `Interval` that implements intervals on the line. It contains the type

```
data Interval t = Interval t t
```

the helper function

```
makeInterval :: (Ord t) => t -> t -> Interval t  
makeInterval l r  | l <= r    = Interval l r  
                  | otherwise = error "bad interval"
```

and some utility functions about intervals.

Here, my interest lies in multidimensional intervals (d-intervals), those objects that are composed of d intervals. I want to separately consider d-intervals that are the union of d disjoint intervals on the line (multiple interval) from those that are the union of d interval on d separate lines (track interval). With distinct algorithmic treatments in mind, I think it would be nice to have two distinct types (even if both are lists of intervals here) such as

```
import qualified Interval as I

-- Multilple interval  
newtype MInterval t = MInterval [I.Interval t]  

   -- Track interval  
newtype TInterval t = TInterval [I.Interval t]
```

to allow for distinct sanity checks, e.g.

```
makeMInterval :: (Ord t) => [I.Interval t] -> MInterval t
makeMInterval is = if foldr (&&) True [I.precedes i i' | (i, i') <- zip is (tail is)]  
                   then (MInterval is)
                   else error "bad multiple interval"


makeTInterval :: (Ord t) => [I.Interval t] -> TInterval t
makeTInterval  = TInterval
```

I now get to the point, at last! But some functions are naturally concerned with both multiple intervals and track intervals. For example, a function `order` would return the number of intervals in a multiple interval or a track interval. What can I do? Adding

```
-- Dimensional interval
data DInterval t = MIntervalStuff (MInterval t) | TIntervalStuff (TInterval t)
```

does not help much, since, if I understand well (correct me if I'm wrong), I would have to write

```
order :: DInterval t -> Int
order (MIntervalStuff (MInterval is)) = length is
order (TIntervalStuff (TInterval is)) = length is
```

and call `order` as `order (MIntervalStuff is)` or `order (TIntervalStuff is)` when `is` is a `MInterval` or a `TInterval`. Not that great, it looks odd. Neither I want to duplicate the function (I have many functions that are concerned with both multiple and track intevals, and some other d-interval definitions such as equal length multiple and track intervals).

I'm left with the feeling that I'm completely wrong and have missed some important point about types in Haskell (and/or can't forget enough here about OO programming). So, quite a newbie question, what would be the best way in Haskell to deal with such a situation? Do I have to forget about introducing `MInterval` and `TInterval` and go with one type only?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Garulfo

Comment: Just as an aside, `foldr (&&) True == and`.

Answer (score 5):

Edit: this is the same idea as sclv's answer; his links provide more information on this technique.

What about this approach?

```
data MInterval = MInterval --multiple interval
data TInterval = TInterval --track interval

data DInterval s t = DInterval [I.Interval t]

makeMInterval :: (Ord t) => [I.Interval t] -> Maybe (DInterval MInterval t)
makeMInterval is = if foldr (&&) True [I.precedes i i' | (i, i') <- zip is (tail is)]
  then Just (DInterval is)
  else Nothing

order :: DInterval s t -> Int
order (DInterval is) = length is

equalOrder :: DInterval s1 t -> DInterval s2 t -> Bool
equalOrder i1 i2 = order i1 == order i2

addToMInterval :: DInterval MInterval t -> Interval t -> Maybe (DInterval MInterval t)
addToMInterval = ..
```

Here the type DInterval represents multi-dimension intervals, but it takes an extra type parameter as a phantom type.  This extra type information allows the typechecker to differentiate between different kinds of intervals even though they have exactly the same representation.

You get the type safety of your original design, but all your structures share the same implementation.  Crucially, when the type of the interval doesn't matter, you can leave it unspecified.

I also changed the implementation of your makeMInterval function; returning a `Maybe` for a function like this is much more idiomatic than calling error.

More explanation on Maybe:

Let's examine your function `makeInterval`.  This function is supposed to take a list of Interval's, and if they meet the criteria return a multiple interval, otherwise a track interval.  This explanation leads to the type:

```
makeInterval :: (Ord t) =>
  [I.Interval t] ->
  Either (DInterval TInterval t) (DInterval MInterval t)
```

Now that we have the type, how can we implement it?  We'd like to re-use our makeMInterval function.

```
makeInterval is = maybe
                   (Left $ DInterval TInterval is)
                   Right
                   (makeMInterval is)
```

The function `maybe` takes three arguments: a default `b` to use if the Maybe is `Nothing`, a function `a -> b` if the Maybe is `Just a`, and a `Maybe a`.  It returns either the default or the result of applying the function to the Maybe value.

Our default is the track interval, so we create a Left track interval for the first argument.  If the maybe is `Just (DInterval MInterval t)`, the multiple interval already exists so all that's necessary is to stick it into the Right side of the either.  Finally, `makeMInterval` is used to create the multiple interval.

Comment: Many thanks, to all of you. This is exactly that I was looking for. Furthermore I think I shall be able to consider my additional properies (all intervals have the same length, unit length, ...) using the same approach, something like data DInterval a b t = DInterval [I.Interval t], where a will act as MInterval orTInterval and b as Balanced, Unit, ...

Comment: As for the Maybe note ... the only thing I really understood about Maybe is that it is an important concept. I mean I understand Maybe locally (to represent a computation that might fail), a little bit less how to use >>= with Maybe (in some tutorials I found this nice). However, using it for every day is still not clear for me. If I want to define both makeInterval and makeMInterval with Maybe, I'm in trouble since in makeMInterval since I'm expecting [I.Interval t], not [Maybe (I.Interval t)].  Ok I need to read more about this.

Comment: Have you read LYAH's Maybe chapter?  http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#getting-our-feet-wet-with-maybe

Answer (score 3):

What you want are types with the same structure and common operations, but which may be distinguished, and for which certain operations only make sense on one or another type. The idiom for this in Haskell is Phantom Types.

1. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Phantom_type
2. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Wrapper_types
3. http://blog.malde.org/index.php/2009/05/14/using-a-phantom-type-to-label-different-kinds-of-sequences/
4. http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2007/04/phantom-types-for-real-problems.html

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a typeclass. Typeclasses is how overloading is done in Haskell. A type class is a common structure that is shared by many types. In your case you want to create a class of all types that have a `order` function:

```
 class Dimensional a where
     order :: a -> Int
```

This is saying there's a class of types `a` called `Dimensional`, and for each type belonging to this class there's a function `a -> Int` called `order`. Now you need to declare all your types as an belonging to the class:

```
 instance Dimensional MInterval where
     order (MInterval is) = length is
```

and so on. You can also declare functions that act on things that are from a given class, this way:

```
 isOneDimensional :: (Dimensional a) => a -> Bool
 isOneDimensional interval = (order interval == 1)
```

The type declaration can be read "for all types `a` that belong to typeclass `Dimensional`, this functions takes `a` and returns a `Bool`".

I like to think about classes as algebraic structures in mathematics (it's not quite the same thing as you can't enforce some logical constraints, but...): you state what are the requirements for a type to belong to some class (in the analogy, the operations must be defined over a set for it to belong to a certain algebraic construction), and then, for each specific type you state what is the specific implementation of the required functions (in the analogy, what are the specific functions for each specific set).

Take, for example, a group. Groups must have an identity, an inverse for each element and a multiplication:

```
 class Group a where:
        identity :: a
        inverse  :: a -> a 
        (<*>)      :: a -> a -> a
```

and Integers form a group under addition:

```
instance Group Integer where:
        identity  = 0
        inverse x = (- x)
        x <*> y     = x + y
```

Note that this will not solve the repetition, as you have to instantiate each type.

Answer (score 0):

consider the use of typeclasses to show similarities between different types. See the haskell tutorial[1] about classes and overloading for help.

[1]: http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html haskell tutorial